How to highlight max and min datapoints on powerbi line chart from measure rather than column
I have a line chart in PBI.
The values come from this measure;
`Average LC = AVERAGE(claims[LC])`

The X axis is a field parameter;
_Par Date Type = {("W", NAMEOF('_DT Date Table'[Week Starting]), 0),("M", NAMEOF('_DT Date Table'[Month Starting]), 1), ("Y", NAMEOF('_DT Date Table'[Year]), 2)}

I want to highlight the Max and Min datapoint labels (red and green) using a measure and conditional formatting.
I had this working but it broke inexplicably and I can’t fix it.
I had this measure;
Min Average =
    VAR SelectedPar = SELECTEDVALUE('_Par Date Type'[_Par Date Type Order])
    VAR SelectedContext =
        SWITCH(
            TRUE(),
            SelectedPar = 0, "W",
            SelectedPar = 1, "M",
            SelectedPar = 2, "Y",
            "None"
        )
    VAR Result =
    SWITCH(
        SelectedContext,
        "W",
        MINX(
            ALLSELECTED('_DT Date Table'[Week Starting]),
            AVERAGE(claims[LC])
        ),
        "M",
        MINX(
            ALLSELECTED('_DT Date Table'[Month Starting]),
            AVERAGE(claims[LC])
        "Y",
        MINX(
            ALLSELECTED('_DT Date Table'[Year]),
            AVERAGE(claims[LC])
    RETURN
    Result

I then used;
Is Min Lifecycle For Period Selected =
VAR MinValue = [Min Average]
VAR CurrentValue = [Average LC]
RETURN IF(CurrentValue = MinValue, 1, 0)

I had equivalents for MAX.
I then used;
Lifecycle Max/Min Field Value =
IF(
    [Is Max Lifecycle For Period Selected] = 1, "Red",
    IF([Is Min Lifecycle For Period Selected] = 1, "#2AC350", "Light Grey")
)

The problem I am now facing is that each data point goes red.
When putting the data in a table visual I can see that the problem is I get a different minimum value for each row (which equals the lifecycle).
It wasn’t doing this before and the same figure showed in each row of the table.
Is my approach (although clearly flawed) along the right approach or should I change it entirely?
How do I fix this?
I’ve watched various YouTube videos but all seem to be on a column rather than than measure and ChatGPT just keeps looping over failed ideas.
